# NSAppTransportSecurity option not listed in Xcode plist editor

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, app-transport-security

I am trying to add the App Transport Security keys to my Info.plist as described in the following Apple tech note https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016240-CH1-SW3 (Exclusions section)

When I edit the Info.plist file, I did the following:

1. Click on the '+' next to 'Information Property List' to create a new top level key
2. Clicked the dropdown to select "NSAppTransportSecurity'

However Xcode doesn't list the option in the drop down list (screenshot below).

Do I need to open the Info.plist file in a text editor and edit this manually?! Or am I missing some (probably obvious!) step?

I'm using Xcode 7.0.1

Thanks

[image]

Comment: No need to open it in a text editor, just type the key there or paste  it there instead of looking for auto-complete option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode 7.1 lists the option in the dropdown (*App Transport Security Settings*). In earlier versions you need to type the raw key *NSAppTransportSecurity* and set the type to dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Simply it is not already present in Xcode 7.0

You can use anyway Xcode but I suggest you to open the plist file with a text editor and add this to allow all connections to **all** domains:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <!-- .......................... -->
        <!-- Other keys already present -->
        <!-- .......................... -->

        <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>

           <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
           <true/>

        </dict>

    </dict>
    </plist>
```

To add specific exceptions to a list of domains add this instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <!-- .......................... -->
    <!-- Other keys already present -->
    <!-- .......................... -->

    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>

        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>

            <key>domain.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>

        </dict>
    </dict>

</dict>
</plist>
```

NSIncludesSubdomains is not necessary but permits to access subdomains like wiki.domain.com, blog.domain.com etc.

For a detailed tutorial have a look at [this blog post](http://www.soortapp.com/ios-9-nsapptransportsecurity-tutorial/)